# MySQL - specific columns on join?

Tags: mysql, sql

When making a join (inner, left outer, right outer or whatever), how can I specify which columns on the table to join into the original table?

Consider the following example:

```
SELECT FirstName FROM User LEFT OUTER JOIN Provider ON User.ProviderID = Provider.ID
```

This would select FirstName from user, but select everything from Provider. How can I specify which parts of Provider should be included in the resultset?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This will only include `User.FirstName` **and `Provider.ProviderID`** in the final resultset:

```
SELECT User.FirstName, Provider.ProviderID FROM User LEFT OUTER JOIN Provider ON User.ProviderID = Provider.ID
```

Comment: won't this select everything from Provider?

Comment: ain't this what he wants? at least that is what I am understanding from *but select everything from Provider*

Comment: You would need to look at the last sentence :). "How can I specify which parts of Provider should be included in the resultset?"

Comment: Taking in consideration that in his query no field from Provider are specified, and the part with *but select everything from Provider*, I stay to the conclusion that this is what he wants/needs

Comment: It was indeed what I wanted. Thanks. I don't understand why people voted your post down.

Comment: Because his question clearly states that he wants specific columns from Provider table to be merged into original table: "How can I specify which parts of Provider should be included in the resultset?"
This answer doesn't solve the problem. It does the opposite.

Answer (score 6):

```
  SELECT User.FirstName, Provider.ID, Provider.YourExtraColumnname, Provider.YourExtraColumnname2 FROM User LEFT OUTER JOIN Provider ON User.ProviderID = Provider.ID
```

Answer (score 4):

```
         SELECT `User`.FirstName, Provider.* 
           FROM `User`
LEFT OUTER JOIN Provider 
             ON `User`.ProviderID = Provider.ID
```

1. You use the table name before the column, or if you alias your tables, you can use the alias.

E.g. `LEFT OUTER JOIN Provider p` and then you could access providers id on the select clause like this:

```
 SELECT `User`.FirstName, p.ID
```

2. I added backticks around the table name `User`, because it is a reserved word for MySQL

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the specific items to choose, like:

```
SELECT User.FirstName, Provider.ID, Provider.Name FROM User LEFT OUTER JOIN Provider ON User.ProviderID = Provider.ID
```