# how to combine more than one mysql query into single query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i have 3 different queries like below:

```
$query = "select category_id,category_name from category";
$result = $this->Dbmodel->customQueryResult($query);

$query = "select location,location_name from sub_category";
$result_one = $this->Dbmodel->customQueryResult($query);

$query = "select category_date,category_month from other_category";
$result_two = $this->Dbmodel->customQueryResult($query);
```

here i am calling `mysql` server 3 times to execute my `query` and getting the `result` thereby..

now i am thinking how can i reduce `mysql` call so that all these 3 `query` gets executed in `one` single query so making only 1 call to `mysql server` and displaying all different results to user using `php`

how can i do this.. any help or suggestion would be a great help.. thanks in advance

Comment: yes ofcourse it could be done but without table structure its impossible to suggest anything.

Comment: What are the foreign keys?

Comment: actually  i am just thinking how can i make only one call instead of three call

Comment: For these purpose exists JOIN, but it depend of table structure...

Comment: none of the three tables are dependent or related to each other

Comment: if they are not related then u can do union but rember they all will come in the same record set and if you apply them for menu or drop-down then u need to do loop multiple time and reset the cursor to first position.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty Sir can you show me some little example code...

Comment: ok so what u intend to do with the result I have to make an example based on it..

Comment: In c# you can do this by terminating each query by putting ";" and then using datareader.nextresult(). You can search equivalent features in php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've described is an SQL UNION.

Below is an example query you could use to achieve your goal:

```
SELECT category_id,category_name FROM category
UNION
SELECT location,location_name FROM sub_category
UNION
SELECT category_date,category_month FROM other_category
```

Example usage:

```
$query = 'SELECT category_id, category_name FROM category
            UNION
            SELECT location, location_name FROM sub_category
            UNION
            SELECT category_date, category_month FROM other_category';
$result = $this->Dbmodel->customQueryResult($query);

echo 'CategoryID: ' . $result['category_id'] . '<br />';
echo 'Category Name: ' . $result['category_name'] . '<br />';
echo 'Location: ' . $result['location'] . '<br />';
echo 'Location Name: ' . $result['location_name'] . '<br />';
echo 'Category Date: ' . $result['category_date'] . '<br />';
echo 'Category Month: ' . $result['category_month'];
```

Keep in mind, in case you need to select fields with identical names from different tables to use SQL aliases.  An example of an alias:

```
SELECT category_id AS `catID` FROM category
```

Instead of $result['category_id'], you would use $result['catID'] instead.

Comment: Sir ... this is what i am looking for..but now how i can display all the different result to users using php

Comment: I have adjusted my answer.  Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

THIS WILL BE EXACT QUERY

```
$query = "select category.category_id,category.category_name, sub_category.location,sub_category.location_name,other_category.category_date,other_category.category_month from category,sub_category,other_category";
```

You can use joint properties something like that.

```
$query = "select * from category, sub_category, other_category";
```

Note: on *, you can read this question [MySQL - specific columns on join?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6826342/mysql-specific-columns-on-join)

Comment: none of the three tables are dependent or related to each other

Comment: Simply select all columns from three tables and then work on output array. do not made any condition for joint.

Comment: This query will solve your problem.
select comments.ref, posts.id FROM comments,posts ;

Comments and posts two tables are selected and ref column from comments is select and id from posts is selected.

Answer (score 1):

```
As you are saying none of the tables are related, you have to fetch 3 queries.
```

You shouldn't combine queries, if there is no any relation. Otherwise it will give you ambiguous data.

We use sub-queries, joins when there is some relation to minimize queries.

Anyways you can get 3 queries result, if 1st, 2nd column have same data type and you can identify from 3rd column it's table name.

```
SELECT category_id,category_name, 'category' FROM category
UNION
SELECT location,location_name, 'sub_category' FROM sub_category
UNION
SELECT category_date,category_month, 'other_category' FROM other_category
```

Comment: @Muhammad: It will give so ambiguous data. You won't able to understand which one is of what type.

Comment: @Muhammad: I have updated my answer. You can add third column which will give you table name and you can differentiate results.

Answer (score 0):

If the tables are related you could use joins. If that not the case you could use mysql UNION

It would be something like ...

```
$query = "select category_id,category_name from category UNION select location,location_name from sub_category UNION select category_date,category_month from other_category";
```

Comment: none of the three tables are dependent or related to each other

Answer (score 0):

If all 3 Query have same data then we can Combine all 3 queries, Otherwise it would be not useful.

The Other way, Would be as Follows

Select c.category_id, c.category_name,
l.location,l.location_name,
o.category_date,o.category_month
 from category C,
 sub_category l,
 other_category o

But Above would does get the Meaningful Data.